# How to filter Firebase data of Map<String, dynamic>

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

**How can i filter list based on role.**
[image]

Currently I am using below `stream` for showing all data but I want to show data based on role of user.

```
stream: firebaseFirestore.collection('messages').where('users', arrayContains: userId).orderBy('timestamp', descending: true).snapshots()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Firestore supports an `array-contains` clause in its queries, that condition only matches if you specify the exact, complete array item. There's no operator to filter on a partial array item.

The common workaround is to add an additional array field with just the UIDs (e.g. `uids`) to each document and then filter on that with:

```
firebaseFirestore.collection('messages').where('uids', arrayContains: userId)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but that won't solve my problem as my query is how can i filter data inside Map<String, dynamic> because i'm already filtering data like this
  .where('uids', arrayContains: userId) as you can see in my question.

But i would like to filter out data based on "role" of user because i have many users and what if i would like to show only that type of users who has "role" : 1.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you data structure then, but if your `role` is nested under `dataFrom` when you can do `where("dataFrom.role", equalTo: "1")`. To combine that with your existing filter you likely will need to create a composite index on the two fields, which you can either do in the console or by following the link in the error message that gets logged when you run the code without creating the index.